# what is infopath and how to use in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint

I want to know about infopath and also whether it is good to use instead of webparts or not ?

Comment: FWIW: http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/infopath/infopath-2010-features-and-benefits-HA101806949.aspx: *"Developers can create advanced forms for departmental and enterprise business processes, including composite applications and workflow sequences, with InfoPath 2010, Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010, and SharePoint Designer 2010—using little or no code."*

Comment: yeah.that will be defination of the Inforpath but I want small sample for that so I can start using Infopath with SP 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

below link is "Introduction to Microsoft Office InfoPath 2007"

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/introduction-to-microsoft-office-infopath-2007-HA010163577.aspx

and "Integration of InfoPath with SharePoint"

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/srikanchar/InfopathIntegrationwithSPS11142005045822AM/InfopathIntegrationwithSPS.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Infopath is a MS Office tool/program that lets you define and use XML based forms.

Start here with [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_InfoPath).

> **Integration with SharePoint**
>
> The most common usage of InfoPath is
>   to integrate it with Microsoft
>   SharePoint technology using InfoPath
>   Form Services (included in the
>   enterprise commercial version of MOSS)
>   or as the separate Microsoft Office
>   Forms Server 2007 product. In
>   SharePoint, a "Form Library" can be
>   created and developed by using
>   InfoPath. InfoPath fields will be
>   exported as "Columns" in the library
>   and can be directly read in SharePoint
>   or be used as part of web services
>   results in workflow development.

Comment: Thanx for the quick help.how can I start with Infopath and integrate in SP2010?